# excel runs slower after exportasfixedformat

Tags: excel, pdf, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

The following code snippet is running in Excel/Office 2007:

```
If Dir(Filenamepath) <> "" Then 'don't overwrite the packing list if it exists
Else
    PackList.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:=Filenamepath, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False 'True
End If
```

This loops through a number of times, e.g. 10, in order to create twn packing lists.  Whenever the ExportAsFixedFormat part of the loop runs, all the code afterwards runs slowly.

I have run an experiment where I delete just one of the many existing PDF files (in Filenamepath) (so that the code will enter the "export as PDF" loop just once).  The code runs fast before the one PDF is created, and then slowly afterwards.  If I don't delete any PDF files, so that when the code is run, the loop "export as PDF" is never entered, the code never slows down.

I have tried:

```
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

At the beginning of my code, but the result of my experiment stays the same, so this does not seem to be the problem.

Why does ExportAsFixedFormat cause the code to slow down so drastically, and what can be done about it?

28 Dec 2017 update: still no resolution, however it seems from searching other questions related to ExportAsFixedFormat causing Excel to crash (such as 35857728) that this is a common problem.  Recently, Excel crashes (but only sometimes) while attempting to generate a PDF, where previously it would just run slowly.  I have tried changing my default printer, uninstalling other VBA macros, uninstalling Windows updates (all suggestions by other uses to address ExportAsFixedFormat issues).  Nothing seems to help.

The ONLY resolution that seems to work is if I change the file type of the export from PDF to XPS (the other ExportAsFixedFormat option).  For my situation, I can live with the XPS filetype, and I can always convert the files to PDF's later.  I have not verified that this speeds up the macro (my original problem) but at least it seems to help with the crashing).